# Change Upload File path in c# asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asyncfileupload

I want to change the path from the current root folder to mt C: or desktop for example,
i'm using this code:

```
public IActionResult About(IList<IFormFile> files)
{

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                        .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                        .FileName
                        .Trim('"');
        filename = hostingEnv.WebRootPath + $@"\{filename}";

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fs);
            fs.Flush();
        }
    }


    return View();
}
```

I tried changing the webrootpath or manipulating after the$@ but to no avail.

Comment: Are you trying to acces a file outside of your app roots folder ?

Comment: Yes i am...............

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information. You should make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least tell us what error you are getting, if you are even getting one.

Comment: I currently can upload a file and it saves in the wwwroot file in my visual studio project folder, i want to save it in  a different location ( Desktop for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't acces any file outside your web app root file unless you use one of theses otpions :

1. Use an upload file controler :

   ```
   <input  type="file" name="UploadFile" /></span>
   ```

In wich you have to let the user specify the file HE wants to upload.

2. You can use FTP, you'll have to make a server yourself.

I'm not an ASP expert, but i know this one thing :

Being able to freely go through the files in the C:\ using code behind of a web application would represent a MAJOR LACK of security.

EDIT :

And this is **THE** way to give a file to your users :

```
    private void UserDownload(string fileOutPutName, string fileType, string fileContentPath)
    {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Server.UrlPathEncode(fileOutPutName));
        Response.ContentType = fileType;
        try
        {
            Response.WriteFile(fileContentPath);
        }
        catch
        {}
        Response.End();
    }
```

The file is gonna end up in their browser's download folder. Being able to write a file into a client's C:\ would be as unsafe as accessing his C:\

ASP.NET won't let you do that

Comment: I currently can upload a file and it saves in the wwwroot file in my visual studio project folder, i want to save it in  a different location ( Desktop for example)

Comment: Seriously...the only place you can save a file into a user's environnement is in the dowload folder of his browser, see my answer's edit

Comment: I also tried that you know, telling myself it would not be THAT dramatic to access a file on the client's desktop. But it's a web application ! Imagine if any web site COULD access your c:\, i'll be the first to create a function that delete alsmost your whole computer as soon as you reach my web page. FTP migth help you, again i say i'm not an FTP expert, but i know that it can be done easely if you read about it

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I think you're misunderstanding his question. What if he doesn't want to say the file on the server where the application is running and wants to save it on the network path? Not being able to access any other folder other than the WebRoot seems like a major limitation. Most applications don't store uploaded content on their server path but save it instead on a CDN or a UNC path

Comment: @RaniBalaa did you figure the solution out?

Comment: Ho... well i tried a lot too you know, i now use FTP to access outside my app folder... If you know how to access folder outside the app, even i would be interested

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I've added a bug to the aspnet repo on github. I'll update here when I get a response back

Answer (score 2):

The other answer seems to have confused downloading files from a server with uploading files.

`IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` is simply the path to the static files on your server (by default: the wwwroot folder). To save an uploaded file to a directory other than WebRootPath, you can simply replace the `hostingEnv.WebRootPath` with a full path to any other directory on the machine.

```
public IActionResult About(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue
                        .Parse(file.ContentDisposition)
                        .FileName
                        .Trim('"');
        filename = @"C:\UploadsFolder" + $@"\{filename}";

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filename))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fs);
            fs.Flush();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

However, you must make sure that this directory exists, and that your application has permission to write to that directory. Running the app in debug from Visual Studio will run it as your user, so it will need to be a directory that you have access to write to. In a production environment, that gets more complicated and depends on your hosting setup.